# Android Bluetooth rescanning cause Bluetooth lost

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, network-scan

I am working on Bluetooth related application where I provide user a list of nearby Bluetooth devices and also I provide a rescan button to restart scanning process. When user comes to this view application start discovery process and if application founds device it get display in a list. But if the user presses rescan button, first application clear list and then restart scanning process then application fails to list same device again.
I don't know why application fails to rescan same device again.

Comment: can you please share your code sample ?

Comment: @AbhijitMuke - I only call bluetoothadapter.startDiscovery() and I am using broadcast receiver to receive bluetooth device found system notification...

Comment: I just want to see is your `BroadcastReceiver ` get registered or not?

Answer (score 0):

Check out code below :

Starting search

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery(); 
mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
String action = intent.getAction();
```

Finding devices

```
if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) 
{
    // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
   mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
}
}
};

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND); 
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Discovery procedure is in some sense a probabilistic, so if you can't get identical lists in two sequential calls it is ok. I'd rather wonder are you able to enumerate *any* other BT-devices during subsequent calls. And if answer is always 'yes', and you experience problems with that only device, check if it is operating correctly. If after first successful call you can't enumerate the devices - either your code is incorrect or your device you're using for debugging works not very well (that's happens quite often in the Android World).